# Installing downloaded APK after accidentally denying

Tags: installation, apk, unknown-sources

I was trying to install a downloaded APK onto my Pixel 3.  During the initial install attempt I was presented with a screen that looked approximately like this one (without the added emphasis on the correct 'Install anyway' option):

[image]

I took one quick glance of this screen before concluding "big green button, that must be what I want here!".  Which was a substantial error, because the big, green button in fact denies the app install.  Oops.

And now what's happening is when I go back to the APK and try the install process again, I'm no longer prompted about whether or not I want to 'Install anyway'.  Instead it just goes straight to the "App not installed" screen.  The one with the gray triangle on it.

How do I get the device to forget that I denied installation to this APK, so that I can successfully install it?

Comment: You can [disable Play Protect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51797048/9165920).

Comment: But that could be a security risk if you consider Google a life saver :)